# nginx is giving 404 error on page reload of my production vue-cli app

Tags: vue.js, nginx, vue-router, nginx-config, vue-cli-3

I know this is a known problem even explained in vue-cli docs when you use history mode in Vue Router.

> If you are using Vue Router in history mode, a simple static file server will fail. For example, if you used Vue Router with a route for /todos/42, the dev server has been configured to respond to localhost:3000/todos/42 properly, but a simple static server serving a production build will respond with a 404 instead.
>
> To fix that, you will need to configure your production server to
>   fallback to index.html for any requests that do not match a static
>   file.

But I'm already doing this in my config file and the problem persists when I reload the page manually.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my.domain.name.com;
  rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
}

server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name my.domain.name.com;

    root /var/www/my-frontend-dist-root;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
location ~*.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|ta$
        expires 365d;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/my.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/my.error.log debug;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.name/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.name/privkey.pem;
    keepalive_timeout   60;
ssl_ciphers "ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aN$
    ssl_protocols           TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhp-2048.pem;

    proxy_buffers 16 64k;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you restart Nginx after configuration change? https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/nginx-linux-restart/

Comment: @ux.engineer   I did. :-(    I'ts strange. In some routes the app reloads ok. But in others just gives 404 with this config.

Comment: Do you have Vue Router set to history mode in config options "mode: 'history'," ?